# How to show a Div background-image on TImage

Tags: html, delphi, background-image, captcha

I have an application that collects information from various sites to fill my database. I'm stuck on this [site](http://www.tjms.jus.br/cpopg5/open.do) that has a captcha. I need to show the captcha for my users. The problem is that the image is in a `background-image` in a `DIV`.

The `DIV id` is `captchaCodigo`.

I know how to get elements by id and name, work with values and etc. But i don't know how to obtain this picture or the url.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is `base64 encoding` , You need to garb it form the html code and convert it to bitmap do NOT forget to send the `uuidCaptcha` with your post request that is the ID that identify the captcha you entered in your program.

```
uses Soap.EncdDecd, IdHTTP, System.StrUtils, pngimage;

Function _ExtractBetweenTags(Const s, LastTag, FirstTag: string; TrimTags: Boolean = True): string;
var
  pLast,pFirst,pNextFirst : Integer;
begin
  pFirst := Pos(FirstTag,s);
  pLast := Pos(LastTag,s);
  while (pLast > 0) and (pFirst > 0) do begin
    if (pFirst > pLast) then // Find next LastTag
      pLast := PosEx(LastTag,s,pLast+Length(LastTag))
    else
    begin
      pNextFirst := PosEx(FirstTag,s,pFirst+Length(FirstTag));
      if (pNextFirst = 0) or (pNextFirst > pLast) then begin
        if TrimTags then begin
          Result := Trim(StringReplace(Trim(Copy(s,pFirst,pLast-pFirst+Length(LastTag))), LastTag, '', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]));
          Result := Trim(StringReplace(Result, FirstTag, '', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]));
        end
        else
        Result := Trim(Copy(s,pFirst,pLast-pFirst+Length(LastTag)));
        Exit;
      end
      else
        pFirst := pNextFirst;
    end;
  end;
  Result := '';
end;

procedure TForm4.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Input: TStringStream;
  Output: TBytesStream;
  sTmp, uuidCaptcha, captchaCodigo: string;
  IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  Graphic: TGraphic;
begin
  IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    IdHTTP.AllowCookies := True;
    IdHTTP.HandleRedirects := True;
    IdHTTP.Request.Connection := 'keep-alive';
    IdHTTP.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36';
    sTmp := IdHTTP.Get('http://www.tjms.jus.br/cpopg5/imagemCaptcha.do');
    uuidCaptcha := _ExtractBetweenTags(sTmp, '"}', '"uuidCaptcha": "'); // You need this when you send the post request
    captchaCodigo := _ExtractBetweenTags(sTmp, '", "labelValorCaptcha":', 'base64,');
    mmo1.Lines.Add(captchaCodigo);
    Input := TStringStream.Create(captchaCodigo, TEncoding.ASCII);
    try
      Output := TBytesStream.Create;
      try
        Soap.EncdDecd.DecodeStream(Input, Output);
        Output.Position := 0;
        Graphic := TPngImage.Create;
        try
          Graphic.LoadFromStream(Output);
          img1.Picture.Bitmap.Assign(Graphic);  // Your Image loads here
        finally
          Graphic.Free;
        end;
      finally
        Output.Free;
      end;
    finally
      Input.Free;
    end;
  finally
    IdHTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Works! Thanks you!

Answer (score 1):

the captcha is very specific, if You use his web link, it will change its text.

I solved that mystery few days ago, the only way is to take a screenshot of this..

here is some lines of my code (it's not pretty, I am still working on finetune, but working perfectly):

main procedure , that saving bitmap to TImage:

```
 procedure TForm1.elscreenshot(var elid:string;imid:integer);  //elementID  and ImageID
    var
      doc : IHTMLDocument2;
      imgRange : IHTMLControlRange;
      img : IHTMLImgElement;
      render : IHTMLElementRender;

      bmp : TBitmap;
      _hdc : HDC;

      img_NameProp : string;
      img_idx,ii : Integer;
    begin
      doc := embeddedwb1.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
      imgRange := ( doc.body as HTMLBody ).createControlRange as IHTMLControlRange;

      for ii := imid to imid do
        begin
        img_idx:=ii;
    repeat
          img := doc.images.item( img_idx, EmptyParam ) as IHTMLImgElement;
          application.ProcessMessages;
          inc(img_idx);
    until pos('andom',img.href)>0;   // USUALLY CAPTCHA HAS "RANDOM" WORD IN ITS HREF   - IN YOUR CASE IT's name is uuidCaptcha 




   img_NameProp := Utf8ToAnsi( UTF8Encode( img.nameProp ) );


        begin
          render := ( img as IHTMLElementRender );

          bmp := TBitmap.Create;
          try
            bmp.Width := img.Width;
            bmp.Height := img.Height;

            _hdc := bmp.Canvas.Handle;

            render.DrawToDC( _hdc );

            Image1.Picture.Assign( bmp );   // <- HERE is happening the screenshot
             cxtextedit1.setfocus;  //focusing my edit box for user interaction
          finally
            bmp.Free;
          end;
          break;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

another code i need for that  (to get element ID and Image ID:

```
procedure TForm1.getcaptcha(var i:integer);
```

//function in procedure body:

```
function GetElementsByClassName(ADoc: IDispatch; const strClassName: string): IHTMLElement;
var
  vDocument: IHTMLDocument2;
  vElementsAll: IHTMLElementCollection;
  vElement: IHTMLElement;
  I, ElementCount: Integer;
begin
  Result := nil;
  ElementCount := 0;
  if not Supports(ADoc, IHTMLDocument2, vDocument) then
    raise Exception.Create('Invalid HTML document');
  vElementsAll := vDocument.all;
  for I := 0 to vElementsAll.length - 1 do
    if Supports(vElementsAll.item(I, EmptyParam), IHTMLElement, vElement) then
      if SameText(vElement.className, strClassName) then
      begin
        Result := vElement;
      end;
end;
```

the procedure

```
  var
        x:integer;
           Doc3 :  IHTMLDocument3;
          cpt : ihtmlelement;
          el:string;
        begin

             Doc3 := EmbeddedWB1.Document as IHTMLDocument3;
        cpt:=nil;
        repeat application.processmessages;until embeddedwb1.ReadyState>2;
        repeat
        application.ProcessMessages;
          cpt:=getelementsbyclassname(doc3,'input-captcha input-text');  //here You must fint how its Your element named  (use getinnertext and parse, or something similar
        until cpt<>nil;  //this repeat..until waits for captcha image to be loaded, usually it takes longer than the rest of webpage code (on slower connections)
          if assigned(cpt) then begin
          el:=cpt.id;
        elscreenshot(el,x);
        end;

        end;
```

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't obtain URL to this picture as it is not transferred through standard HTML protocol.

Pictures in such scenarios are usually transferred as data streams and then shown properly on client side.

In your case the image is actually transferred from server to your computer as `base64` string which is then decoded to actual image on your computer.

You could obtain this info with a little clever use of Google Chrome `developer tools` that can be activated with F12 key.

The main reason why this is implemented in such way is to prevent web bots to overcome the `captcha` security.

In fact most sites that use `captcha` protection system use it for a reason.

Most common reason is to prevent web boots to cause havoc on servers by posting various SPAM content on the site.

Another reason is to prevent them from overloading the servers by downloading all site content.

In fact you trying to gather information from that site and storing it in your own database might be in direct violation of sites usage agreement.

And based that the mentioned site is connected to jurisdictional system I'm willing to bet that any information that is posted on the site should not be copied or redistributed in any way.

Comment: My goal with this is not to overload or use some kind of bot for gather automatic information site. I'm just facilitating the work of my clients that have to inform ids of processes and then manually copy the page updates to my system. I'm not wanting to bypass the `captcha` or automate the whole process. I just want to show the `captcha` to my user know what is needed to enter the query and get the updates. ^^